# What scaling to choose for data that is always >0? Does it matter?

Tags: feature-scaling

If I have something like stock price or income that cannot be negative, what scaling should I pursue? Is there research that suggests that centering it at 0 will cause issues? I'd assume so but I wonder if this is proven somewhere? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Scaling for what purpose?

Comment: Sorry. For training a recurrent neural network. I was just experimenting with comparing ARIMA models to RNN's and noticed that if I scale to a center of 0 it wouldn't forecast as well.